# Does PS3 browser handle gzipping?

Tags: gzip

Not sure if this would be a correct place to post, but here it goes.

I've been getting reports form people who try accessing my site from a PS3, that every page appears like a jumble of random characters on a white background, sort of like echoing out a gzipped string as plain text. I'm using nginx.

Does the PS3 browser not support gzipping? Anything I can do except disabling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a PS3 to test with but first thing that you want to do is to ensure that your server is sending back the correct content-encoding information in the headers. That's just to eliminate any possibility that it might be a web-server issue. I once got caught out by this on a regular browser, not the PS3 one.